# Can't open Websphere Portal 7.0 Login Page after its integration with a custom user registry?

Tags: java, c++

I am currently working on a project related to Websphere Portal 7.0 on Windows Server 2008 R2,64 bit. I am trying to integrate websphere portal with my custom user registry.I have completed all the steps required to implement custom user registry in portal as given in IBM documentation.I am adding my custom repository to the default federated repositories of Portal 7.0.I have made the required changes under VMM Federated CUR Properties section in wkplc.properties.I am using configengine.bat file to configure Portal with user registry.
                         But even completing all the steps,when I am trying to open the Portal Login Page through http://ip-address:port_of_portal/wps/portal ,it is throwing an exception on the console:
"Error 500: com.ibm.wps.resolver.data.exceptions.URIProcessingIOException: EJCBD0021E: The URI dav:fs-type1/themes/PageBuilder2/theme.html and parameters [['themeURI'=, 'mime-type'= could not be processed: [EJCBD0021E: The URI dav:fs-type1/themes/PageBuilder2/theme.html and parameters [['themeURI'=, 'mime-type'= could not be processed: EJPSG0002E: Requested Member does not exist.uid=portal,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/null] "
                                                                  and in logs Systemout.log
"EJPSB0005E: Exception occurred during creation of the principal with Name uid=portal,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm and Principal Type USER caused by com.ibm.portal.puma.MemberNotFoundException: EJPSG0002E: Requested Member does not exist.uid=portal,o=defaultWIMFileBasedRealm/null".

Here,"portal" is administrative user in my custom user registry.I am able to access WAS using /ibm/console through user "portal".Please suggest some way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What's happening here is that the 7.0 theme doesn't exist. I'm not sure how this could've happened in your case, but that's what the dav:fs-type1 error message means. Perhaps you have just done a migration?

You can run these ConfigEngine.sh tasks to reinstall the theme.

ConfigEngine.sh action-create-ear-wp.mashup.cc.theme configure-common-component-resources -DWasPassword= -DPortalAdminPwd= .

I don't think you will need to restart the server after this, but you may as well just to be sure.